# OpenGL Texture binding issue from a BMP image

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, textures, bmp

i'm trying to load a BMP image of size 1024x1024 and bind it as a texture in openGL .
for a BMP of size, 256x256, output is as desired.But for a BMP of size 1024x1024, 
 it throws up following error

```
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\lapping-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\lapping.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

the code for loading the BMP,

```
Texture2d* loadBMP( char *fname){
    int i,j, w, h, bits;
    unsigned long l;
    GLubyte c[3];
    Texture2d* tex;
    FILE *fin;
    unsigned char head[54];
    fin = fopen( fname,"rb");
    if( fin == NULL){
        printf("Bitmap '%s' not found\n", fname);
        return NULL;
    }
    fread( head, 54, 1, fin);
    w = (head[21]<<24)|(head[20]<<16)|(head[19]<<8)|head[18]; //returns the width of the image
    h = (head[25]<<24)|(head[24]<<16)|(head[23]<<8)|head[22];//returns the height of the image          
    tex = new Texture2d[1];
    tex->w = w;
    tex->h = h;
    tex->buf = new GLubyte[h*w*4];
    tex->id = avTotalTextures++;
    for(i=h-1;i>=0;i--){
        l = i*w*4;
        for(j=0;j<w;j++){
            fread( c, 1, 3, fin);
            tex->buf[l++] = c[2];
            tex->buf[l++] = c[1];
            tex->buf[l++] = c[0];
            tex->buf[l++] = 255;

        }
    }
    fclose( fin);
    printf("Bitmap_load '%s' loaded\n", fname);
    return tex;
}
```

the code for binding the texture ,

```
void Object3d::bindTexture( Texture2d *t)
{
    if( t == NULL)
        return;
    tex = t;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->buf);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->buf);
    delete [] tex->buf;
    tex->buf = NULL;
}
```

this works well for a BMP of size 256x256. but when i try to get this working for a bmp of 1024x1024 by changing the width and height parameters in

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->buf);
gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->buf);
```

from 0,0 and 256,256 to 1024, 1024 respectively, it throws up the previously mentioned error. i have referred to openGL specification, but couldn't come up with a reason as to why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Could you post the actual error?

Comment: i have posted the error as first code block in my question. the error says `The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\lapping-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\lapping.exe exited with code -1073741819`

Comment: That's not an error, that is just the exit code.

Comment: the IDE displays no errors , just a few warnings which were always there.

Comment: Does the program even crash or?

Comment: The program instead of displaying the 3D model in a viewer, exits and shows up this exit code. I have observed a similar kind of exit code when i tried to render too many triangles multiple times. i'm doubtful if the changes that i made to the width and height parameters(which were 0,0 and 256,256 previously to 1024 and 1024) have made it computationally expensive.

Comment: It's hard to tell when there isn't any error, but then, are you sure that your computer has enough memory to be able to store textures with that size.

Comment: Object3d::bindTexture is that what you call each time you "bind" a texture?

Comment: i'm sure that the computer has enough memory and processing power to handle this. i have run the debugger and got this output, http://i39.tinypic.com/v9ra0.png

Comment: i load the texure from the BMP and then bind it using Object3d::bindTexture . this is done only once in the entire program.

Comment: Calling `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->buf);` is completely redundant, by the way. `gluBuild2DMipmaps (...)` does this for you, once per-mipmap LOD it generates starting with the top most image (with the dimensions you specify). The fact that you pass 0,0 to begin with is an indication that the earlier call does nothing worthwhile.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman  you are right. glTexImage2D  is insignificant here. it is evident when i tried commenting it out . i just restarted the IDE and it runs without errors now . Thanks , vallentin & Andon. :)